# SQL: Display results from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mysql-error-1064

I have two tables:

Jobs

```
job_title         min_salary  job_id  max_salary 
Public Accountant 4322        1       8777
Assistant         4321        2       9877
President         5432        3       6766
```

Employees

```
emp_id  first_name  last_name  job_id  hire_date
100      Abc        Def        1       2020-12-09
101      Xyz        Efg        2       2020-10-05
102      Hjk        Lmn        3       2019-09-06
```

job_id is common in both tables. I want to display the first and last name and date of joining of the employees who are either Assistant or President...

I am trying to get the output using this:

```
SELECT first_name
     , last_name
     , hire_date 
  FROM employees
 UNION 
     ( SELECT job_title 
         FROM jobs 
        WHERE job_title = 'Assistant' 
           or job_title = 'President');
```

But I am doing something wrong when selecting the required columns...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should to use [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp):

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, hire_date 
FROM Employees
JOIN Jobs ON Employees.job_id = Jobs.job_id
WHERE job_title IN ('Assistant', 'President');
```

Here [live SQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=966568a66acb4458ea51b7fc99b74993&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the query like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tutorial.crunchbase_investments_part1

 UNION

 SELECT *
   FROM tutorial.crunchbase_investments_part2
```

[Source](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-union/#:%7E:text=SQL%20joins%20allow%20you%20to,results%20from%20the%20other%20statement.)